# C# textBox.Text not returning a value inside a TabControl

Tags: c#, text, tabs, textbox, tabcontrol

SOLVED: After rooting round my code it would seem after the 1st textbox would fill it would start reading the others then do nothing, fill the other text boxes and because it read them before it inserted actual data. I have fixed it by ensuring my function runs only after a given point. Thanks to all who answered! :)

Question:
I've hit a bit of a road bump in my project. Couldn't find a question similar to this.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and writing in C# using a Windows Form Application.
I have a Form with TabControl container with 2 tabs, inside each tab is a handful of textBoxes.

I can write my desired data into these textBoxes.
But I cannot read the data from them (Returns a null result)(Note: I can read and write in textBoxes around other areas of my project).

I've narrowed this down to them being inside tabs in the TabControl container
because I have a textbox on the same Form outside of this container and I can read and write to the textBox.

Can anyone provide a sample line of code to read from a textbox inside a TabControl container or explain what I'm doing wrong or what I should be looking for?
Should I be focusing specific tabs/textBoxes when trying to read?
(aka "this.tab1.textBox1.text" or "this.tab1.controls["textBox1"].text").

Edit: since someone asked for code, Its not the problem with my code; its just a problem with taking the string value from the textbox. In the same function I can retrieve strings from various textBoxes in the same project. I have tried:
(Note: works on normal textboxes, not in the container)

```
this.textBox1.Text;
this.textBox2.Text.ToString();
this.Container["textBox1"].Text;
```

inside one of my forms (located in the same form as TabControl) I call a function. this function reads the textbox value then does actions based on the value in it. But it calls a null value which I have found using `MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text.ToString());`
my code:

```
private void myFunction(){//Check Values
    if (textBox1.Text.ToString() != SomeOtherValue){//then
        //Do appropriate action 
    }//If End
}//MyFunction End
```

(For reference: "SomeOtherValue" is a string value I successfully pull from App.Config which I originally put into these textBoxes, so these textboxes do have a value in them before I try to read from them).  The textBoxes are not being drawn/created.

All comments are appreciated!
-Dave.

Comment: You need to show your relevant code to demonstrate problem

Comment: the code isn't the issue, its trying to retrieve the string value inside the textBox.

Comment: But you should show what you tried

Comment: Access to `Textbox.Text` doesn't matter if this textbox is inside TabControl or not. So without seeing your actual code it's hard to make any assumptions what can be wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming it is  a window form tab and not ajax for web application?

Comment: Normally, you can directly retrieve value in textboxes. Please show problem in your code.

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to access the textboxes before they had a chance to be created?   You are not calling the code in a form constructor I hope.

Comment: Updated my question to hopefully shed more light. @SteveWellens I'm not drawing/creating them, their functionality works fine in the rest of my code, just not retrieving a value from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your text box text is actually initialized. If the function fires before the textbox is filled then you will get a null value. I've had issues in the past where the parent control (tab control in your case) wasn't fully initialized before trying to read the component basically a timing issue.

Comment: I will have a look into this. But as far as I'm aware I'm writing into these values and changing them long before I go to read them. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Yes this was exactly the case. After rooting round my code it would seem after the 1st textbox would fill it would start reading the others then do nothing. I have fixed it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access it like the below.  No need to specify the tab control name or index.  BTW, you should not be able to create two textbox with the same name. It doesn't matter which tab you're in.

string txtvalue = textBox1.Text

Comment: I have just tried this (string strTest = textBox1.Text) and showing the result in a message box popup. I'm afraid still returns a null value while the textbox has a value in it. Also every textbox has a unique name yes.

Comment: Can you give details about how bind textboxes in your app.config? @Hughsie28

Comment: @nevra I'm inserting the data into the textboxes using: "This.textBox1.Text = Config.CustomName.ToString();". Config is a class and "CustomName" is defined as a "public static string CustomName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyValue"];" which is how app.config is involved

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the  value from your config file.

```
CustomName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("keyValue");
```

Comment: I could get the value from the config, that wasn't the problem. Solved now thanks :)